# Aliasing address of json schema in pointers to avoid duplication

Tags: json, jsonschema, dry

Is there a way to somehow alias / rename an external schema address to avoid duplicating it in pointers throught a schema?

e.g. consider something along the following lines:

blah://some.url/my-common-schema-version-12.json

```
{
    "definitions":[
        "schema1":{},
        "schema2":{},
    ]
}
```

derived-schema.json

```
{        
    "definitions":[
        "thing1":{
            "$ref":"blah://some.url/my-common-schema-version-12.json#/definitions/schema1"
        },
        "thing2":{
             "$ref":"blah://some.url/my-common-schema-version-12.json#/definitions/schema2"
        },
    ]
}
```

Ideally it would be good to avoid repeating the 'blah://some.url/my-common-schema-version-12.json' bit in derived-schema.json and have a single place where it can be changed.

Having a search around I can't see anything obvious but perhaps there is a way to do it?

Comment: Does this help, https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html

Comment: Hmm yes perhaps using the id field in the imported schema might make that possible

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You define `$id` at the root of your schema. References are relative to the current "Base URI", which is that defined in the closest `$id` value.

Relative references must first be "resolved", which means determining the full address against the initial Base URI (and not finding and fetching the resource, as many believe).

This is very similar to how the anchor tag works in HTML. The value of a `href` attribute of the anchor tag is resolved against the Base URI. So if you write HTML, you're probably already familiar with how this works.

Comment: Also related which might help understanding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Comment: Thank you.  I think the Bundling section here explains what I'm looking for with a concrete example:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#bundling